# How to add more than 2 dictionaries together in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, addition

I am relatively new to python, and I am a student, I made a code which calculates the total marks and percentage, I want to add 9 dictionaries together, I have tried +, combine_dict, merge_dict, and I have been trying to look up for an answer since last few days but can't find anything helpful.. the code is:

```
     name1= input("enter the name of the first student: ")
     marks = {}       
     subjects = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects:
           marks[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name1 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota = sum(marks.values())
           average = float(tota) / len(marks)         

     print ("\n")

     name2= input("enter the name of the second student: ")
     marks1 = {} 

     subjects1 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects1:
           marks1[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name2 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota1 = sum(marks1.values())
           average1 = float(tota1) / len(marks1)         

     print ("\n")

     name3= input("enter the name of the third student: ")

     marks2 = {}          

     subjects2 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects2:
           marks2[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name3 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota2 = sum(marks2.values())
           average2 = float(tota2) / len(marks2)         

     print ("\n")

     name4= input("enter the name of the fourth student: ")
     marks3 = {} 



     subjects3 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects3:
           marks3[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name4 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota3 = sum(marks3.values())
           average3 = float(tota3) / len(marks3)         

     print ("\n")

     name5= input("enter the name of the fifth student: ")

     marks4 = {} 


     subjects4 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects4:
           marks4[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name5 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota4 = sum(marks4.values())
           average4 = float(tota4) / len(marks4)         

     print ("\n")

     name6= input("enter the name of the sixth student: ")


     marks5 = {}         

     subjects5 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects5:
           marks5[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name6 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota5 = sum(marks5.values())
           average5 = float(tota5) / len(marks5)         

     print ("\n")

     name7= input("enter the name of the seventh student: ")

     marks6 = {} 


     subjects6 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects6:
           marks6[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name7 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota6 = sum(marks6.values())
           average6 = float(tota6) / len(marks6)         

     print ("\n")

     name8= input("enter the name of the eighth student: ")
     marks7 = {} 


     subjects7 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects7:
           marks7[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name8 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota7 = sum(marks7.values())
           average7 = float(tota7) / len(marks7)         

     print ("\n")

     name9= input("enter the name of the nineth student: ")
     marks8 = {} 


     subjects8 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects8:
           marks8[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name9 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota8 = sum(marks8.values())
           average8 = float(tota8) / len(marks8)         

     print ("\n")

     name10= input("enter the name of the tenth student: ")

     marks9 = {} 


     subjects9 = ["Accounts","History","Geography","Chemistry","Computer Science","Maths","Add maths", "English"]

     for subject in subjects9:
           marks9[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name10 + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
           tota9 = sum(marks9.values())
           average9 = float(tota9) / len(marks9)

     print ("\n")

     marks10= merge_dicts(marks, marks1, marks2, marks3, marks4, marks5, marks6, marks7, marks8, marks9)

     print ("total marks for whole class are " + marks10 )
```

What I want to do is that in marks10 all the other dictionaries should be added together, So for example

```
marks1=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
marks2=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
marks3=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
marks4=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
marks5=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
marks6=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
marks7=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
marks8=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
marks9=[90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80, 90, 80]
```

I want marks10 to be
marks10=[810,720,810,720,810,720,810,720]
hope it is clear now..

Comment: you mean update the dict values or adding the values inside the dicts?

Comment: It is completely unclear what "adding" dictionaries is supposed to mean.  What would you expect the result to look like?  Can you give an example of the inputs and the expected output, as Python data structures?  Also, use a loop instead of copying the same code ten times.

Comment: What if you had 100 students? Would you copy-paste that code for all of them? :) I suggest looking into using loops; you'll find that generating the final marks becomes easier, too.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Yes, I am asking to add the dict values inside another dict..

Comment: Since your dict is a mapping from subject to a float, merging 2 dicts would overwrite each students grades. Better have a dict that maps `students` to a `(subject, grade)` tuple?

Comment: Hmm... All your `subjects_i` lists are simply copies of original `subjects`. This is just a waste of memory (for the computer) and of time (for you). Just use `subjects`, and condidere using a loop as already suggested.

Comment: Basically what you should do is have all the results in the same dictionary in the first place - probably indexed by the student name (although for a more robust solution that would be inadequate because names aren't unique). so you should have studentmarks = {} and then for each student such as name1 use studentmarks[name1][subject] = score.

Comment: @barny can u please elaborate?

Comment: and the reason I am not using loops is because, I am not good with them yet :3 everytime I use loop somewhere, I screw up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, in the comments:

> and the reason I am not using loops is because, I am not good with them yet :3 everytime I use loop somewhere, I screw up.

You're already using `for` loops to iterate over the `subjects`! :)

Anyway, without using loops to iterate over students, the best you can do to tally up the totals is something terrible like

```
total = {}
for subject in subjects:
    total[subject] = marks1[subject] + marks2[subject] + marks3[subject] + marks4[subject] + marks5[subject] + marks6[subject] + marks7[subject] + marks8[subject] + marks9[subject] + marks10[subject]
```

... so here's an implementation that splits the problem into 3 methods, each one copiously commented. I hope this helps :)

```
subjects = ["Accounts", "History", "Geography", "Chemistry", "Computer Science", "Maths", "Add maths", "English"]


def get_marks(i):
    name = input("Enter the name of student %d: " % i)  # (the name is only used for the subject prompts below)
    if not name:  # If the user doesn't enter a name, don't query for subjects either.
        return  # (implicitly returns None)
    marks = {}
    for subject in subjects:  # Loop over the subjects -- this is OP's code :)
        marks[subject] = float(input("Enter " + name + "'s " + subject + " marks: "))
    return marks


def get_student_marks():
    student_marks = []  # Gather the students' marks (as dicts) into this list.
    for i in range(10):  # Query for 10 students at most.
        marks = get_marks(i + 1)  # Get an individual student's marks as a dict.
        if not marks:  # If no name was entered (and None was thus returned)...
            break  # ... assume the user won't want to enter any more students and break out of the loop.
        student_marks.append(marks)  # Otherwise, save the marks...
    return student_marks  # and when the loop finishes, one way or another, return the list of dicts.


def print_total_marks(student_marks):
    total_marks = dict.fromkeys(subjects, 0)
    for marks in student_marks:  # Loop over each student...
        for subject, mark in marks.items():  # And then each pair of subject/mark...
            # (dict.fromkeys assures us that there's a key for every subject; no need to check at this point.)
            total_marks[subject] += mark  # ... and add that to the total.
    print ("Total marks for whole class are", total_marks)


student_marks = get_student_marks()
print_total_marks(student_marks)
```

(ps. sorry about the long lines; I just wanted to annotate each line on the same line for some clarity.)